# What is the correct usage: In the morning of ... vs. On the morning of ...?

Tags: phrases, compound-adjectives

> **In** the morning of 19 April 2016, Taliban militants attacked a security team.

Or

> **On** the morning of 19 April 2016, Taliban militants attacked a security team .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: @HotLicks, it's good question, because it's tricky usage here, especially to non-native English speakers.

Comment: @Hot Licks Usage of English language is a question, are you making like new definitions of questions round here.

Comment: @Farside -- There is no question.  Do you see a "W word" indicating a question?  Do you see a question mark?

Comment: @Hot Licks I hope I could satisfy you.

Comment: @HotLicks, may be you can suggest an improvement to meet your criteria, and update the question itself? I vote to keep it. It's a good question and is a really tricky moment.

Comment: @HotLicks Have you read the title? There is a perfectly good "W word" there. Besides, who says there has to be a W word for a sentence to constitute a question? I can think of plenty of questions without a W anywhere to be seen.

Comment: Also see at ELL: *[In the morning VS on the morning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18763)*

Comment: @WS2 It seems that the question was edited after the comment.

Comment: @Rathony, it seems the change was rolled back to original state.. because it would totally change the sense of the question. In the question figures a specific morning, the part of the day.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"**on**" is the correct preposition and "**in**" is the incorrect one for this case.

"The morning of" functions as an adjectival phrase clarifying the specific time and date "**on** 19 April 2016". "On" is used because it belongs to the date here, specific part of the day.

The normal language constructions would be:

- **on** + *date* (with the year or without it) or *day of the week*
- **in** + morning, afternoon, evening (*in* the morning, *in* the evening)

But, when we talk about a specific morning, afternoon, or when we describe the part of the day it should be used with **on**:

- **on** the morning of **[date]**,

You can't say "*I will see you **on** the morning*" - it's incorrect.

here's the proof: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time

> In or on?
>
> We use **in** with morning, afternoon, evening and night, but we use **on** when we talk about a specific morning, afternoon, etc., or when we describe the part of the day.

Comment: That construction thing certainly helps, I'm a native speaker but the complexities are often lost upon me.

Comment: But we do say *in the morning* when we specifically mean *tomorrow morning*. Or *If you are going to Henry's Friday afternoon, I will see you in the morning (of Friday)*. This is a devilishly complex area for non-natives to grasp.

Comment: @WS2, you are correct, that's why I provided several cases in my answer, when there is used **on** and when **in**. **In** is used with parts of the day, months, seasons, years. But **on** will be used with public holidays, weekends, when the talk is about a particular special day... and the case which I covered above - we talk about a **specific** morning, afternoon, etc., or when we describe **the part of the day**.

Comment: @Farside +1. It's late at night, but I think you have covered most of it.